# Syntax error on token "TextView", import expected

Tags: android, syntax-error, android-edittext, textview

Syntax error on token "TextView", import expected.
Syntax error on token "EditText", import expected.

I am new to this.  Why do I get these syntax error?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

TextView TextOut;
EditText getInput;
```

Comment: you need to declare variables within a class is my guess, I can't tell if this is your actual code or not.

Comment: I am following a youtube video "Android Tutorial & Lessons 14: using the getText() and setText() methods"  That is the part of the actual code I posted.  I wonder if there is a bug with Android 4.1, the platform I am using to learn from this video.  The instructor showing no error on this video.  Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't look right, I'm not sure about the video in question but java doesn't support variables outside of classes AFAIK. All variables must be declared in a class.

Comment: Could it be the import android.widget.EditText; doesn't work?  Eclipse couldn't link to the android.widget.EditText class for android 4.1?  The instructor is using android 2.2 I believe. Thanks.

Comment: The error says import expected because the only thing that can go outside of classes is package statements or import statements.